# Where do I report a bug about touchpad behaviour?

Tags: gnome, bug-reporting

I found a bug (or probably: unimplemented behaviour) in how the touchpad operates in GNOME 3. I'd like to report it in the appropriate channels (or at least check if it's already reported), but I have no idea with software is responsible for its behaviour. Who knows?

Note that I do not want to report an Ubuntu-specific bug, as described in [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), and the Wiki page [How do I find the right package?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage) also does not describe which package is appropriate for the touchpad handling.

Comment: In case it helps answering the question: the bug is that natural scrolling is only implemented vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Probably running `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell` is the best place to start there.

Comment: @dobey That both reports the bug against a package in Ubuntu, and against (I think) the wrong package. I'd prefer not cluttering those issue trackers with irrelevant issues.

Comment: This is Ask Ubuntu, not Ask GNOME. Yes, you should report a bug against the package in Ubuntu. You don't know if it's the wrong package or not. The devs will determine if it is not, and move it to the correct place, assuming the bug is valid. It is perfectly fine to report such a vague bug against the primary interface where it's experienced.

Comment: I'm asking Ask Ubuntu because I don't know which software Ubuntu uses for handling touchpad interactions - e.g. is it even part of GNOME? But I've reported it in Launchpad now, hope the devs don't mind me wasting their time too much.

Comment: It could be a bug anywhere throughout the stack, so without knowing specifically where the issue occurs, it's not possible to say which package the report belongs against exactly. It requires further debugging to determine that. Which is why you file the report against the level of the stack where you experience the issue. It can be moved later if it's found to be lower in the stack. But there are 5+ plus levels where the issue with a touchpad could exist.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Thanks for making me feel less bad about the report :)